# Как создать Wi-Fi сеть и как к ней подключиться?

Tags: wifi

Вопрос не совсем про программирование, но всё же:

**Вопрос 1:** если есть компьютер, который подключен к интернету по кабелю, и при этом у него есть Wi-Fi адаптер, то можно ли с его помощью сделать свою Wi-Fi сеть?

**Вопрос 2:** у кого-то из соседей была незапароленная Wi-Fi сеть. Какое-то время через неё я сидел в интернете, но через пару дней доступ в интернет пропал. Я бы ещё понял, если бы дело было в том, что владельцы установили пароль, но к точке я всё ещё могу подключиться. Однако когда захожу в интернет, браузер пишет, что соединения нет. В чём может быть дело?

Answer (score 1):

> Вопрос 1:

Можно, в случае если его WiFi-адаптер умеет работать в режимах AP (точка доступа) или ad-hoc (соединение wifi-адаптер-wifi-адаптер).

> Вопрос 2

Варианты: поставили фильтрацию по MAC, сделали настройки и-та прописываемыми вручную, а не автоматом, настроили у себя прокси, вообще отключили интернет.

Comment: "поставили фильтрацию по MAC, сделали настройки и-та прописываемыми вручную, а не автоматом, настроили у себя прокси, вообще отключили интернет"
  Как это понять и как это обойти?

Comment: В общем - никак. Если по каждому пункту:<p>Склонировать МАК<p>Прописать вручную настройки и-нета (шлюз, адрес, маску)<p>Прописать в браузере адрес прокси<p>Ничего, пользоваться другим способом доступа в и-нет<p>